# Unused Argument Error in Shiny Interactive Map

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

I'm trying ot program an interactive map in R using the Shiny package, but I keep running into an error.

The code is;

```
df <- structure(list(VictimSex = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", "F", "H", "M", "N", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    Long = c(-118.2775, -118.3575, -118.606, -118.2585, -118.3967, 
    -118.4697, -118.3965, -118.6103, -118.5317, -118.3294), Lat = c(34.0488, 
    34.2532, 34.2572, 34.0509, 34.0295, 33.9845, 34.1794, 34.1865, 
    34.2208, 33.9745)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive Los Angeles Traffic Collision"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("Gender", h3("Gender"), choices = list("F", "M"), selected = "Female")
    ),
    mainPanel(leafletOutput("map", "100%", 500), 
              plotOutput("bar"))
  )
)

#Define Server logic ---- 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered <- reactive ({
    if (is.null(input$Gender)){
      return(df)
    }
    df %>% filter(VictimSex %in% input$Gender)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(df = filtered(), radius = 2)
  })
}

#Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error I keep running into is: Error in addCircleMarkers: unused argument (df = filtered())

Comment: Did you want: `addCircleMarkers(data = filtered(), radius = 2)`?

Comment: Well, I would like to manage the size of the markers so they don't overlap too much, but if it's causing problems, best to take it out.

Comment: My thought was you meant to use `data = ` instead of `df = ` ... that's all...

Comment: `addCircleMarkers` takes a `data` argument, not `df`...

Comment: Oh you're right. Everything is fixed now, thanks!